# Using keyword in SelectByAttribute expression?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, where-clause

I've used SearchCursor to return the single value of a record (8 digit number)

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, ['PID']):
if row[0] is not None:
        ID = row[0]
    break
```

Now I would like to use 'ID' in a query.

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Table2, "NEW_SELECTION",'ID' == ID)
```

This is not a valid expression and I'm not sure how to make the keyword ID usable.

Answer (score 2):

The concept you are looking for is "string formatting" or "string interpolation"

If you're on python 2.7:

```
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(Table2, "NEW_SELECTION", 'ID = {}'.format(ID))
```

Or

```
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(Table2, "NEW_SELECTION", 'ID = ' + str(ID))
```

Or

```
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(Table2, "NEW_SELECTION", 'ID = %s' % ID)
```

In modern pythons, you can do any of those plus my preferred method:

```
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(Table2, "NEW_SELECTION", f'ID = {ID}')
```

#### Note

These assume your "ID" variable is an integer. If it's not, you'd change them like so (check the use of double and single quotes):

```
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(Table2, "NEW_SELECTION", "ID = '{}'".format(ID))
```